# Linking error after upgrading to VS2017U8 from VS2017U2

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Our Visual C++ project was compiling and linking successfully when running with VS2017U2. I have made changes to a couple of make files in our project to make it compile with VS2017U8. After the change,I see that the compilation is successful but I am getting a linking error here -

2019-02-21 19:41:44 | libvcruntime.lib(std_type_info.obj) : error LNK2005: ___std_type_info_destroy_list already defined in vcruntime.lib(VCRUNTIME140.dll)

2019-02-21 19:41:44 |    Creating library d:/build/ob/sb-21330799/sim-20fq1/sim/build/beta/apps/coreDump/coreDump.lib and object d:/build/ob/sb-21330799/sim-20fq1/sim/build/beta/apps/coreDump/coreDump.exp

2019-02-21 19:41:44 | coreDump.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I have googled on this linking error (LNK2005) but what is strange is why I am getting this error after only doing VS update without doing any code changes? And how to resolve this? Any pointers on this appreciated.

Comment: What were the changes you made to the make files? Since the problem is probably with the make files why not add them to the question.

Comment: Question should be titled "Linking error after making changes to a couple of make files"

Comment: It seems some of the libraries used to build the dll are built with static runtime (/MT option) and some with dll runtime (/MD option). They need to be the same everywhere.